# Parsing XML file with scrapy AUTH needed

Tags: python, xml, authentication, scrapy

My problem is I dont know how to scrap from an xml file when I need to auth to access it.

so my xml file is on url="ftp://ftp.Dom.com/BlaBla/" user="myself" pass="secret".

On scrapy's doc, I found out something similar for html and I tried to adapt it to my needs.

Here is my code atm :

```
class kelly(XMLFeedSpider):
   name = "kelly"
   allowed_domains = []
   start_urls = ["ftp://ftp.Dom.com/BlaBla/"]
   itertag='Job'

   def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
      XMLFeedSpider.__init__(self)
      self.secret_users = {}
      pipe_import = ImportLaunch()
      pipe_import.pipe = Pipe.objects.first()
      pipe_import.save()
      self.pipe_import = pipe_import

   def parse_node(self, response):
      import pdb
      pdb.set_trace()
      return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'username': 'myself', 'password': 'secret'},
                    callback=self.parse_after_log)]


   def parse_after_log(self,response):
      # check login succeed before going on
      if "authentication failed" in response.body:
         self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
         return
         # We've successfully authenticated, let's have some fun!
      else:
         return Request(url="ftp://ftp.Dom.com/BlaBla/kelly_polarbear.xml", callback=self.parse_tastypage)

   def parse_tastypage(self,response,node):
      print 'I passed !!'
```

but my message is still

```
`2012-03-01 12:27:28+0100 [kelly] ERROR: Error downloading <GET ftp://ftp.kellyservices.com`/Polarbear/>: 530 User anonymous cannot log in.
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

How about a simpler approach?

```
import requests
from lxml import objectify

r = requests.get('http://www.example.com/', auth('username','password'))
root = objectify.fromstring(r.result)

# Now root is an object tree representing your XML
```

- [requests' pypi entry](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests)
- [lxml reference](http://lxml.de/)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't worked with `XMLFeedSpider`, but worked with `BaseSpider` from which `XMLFeedSpider` [inherits](http://dev.scrapy.org/browser/scrapy/contrib/spiders/feed.py#L15).

Your .xml file is on an ftp server, but FormRequest creates HTTP POST request, which is usually yielded from a `parse` method when a page with the authentication form was loaded. So i think it won't work here.

There is [HttpAuthMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpauth) for passing through [basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), but looks like it won't work with FTP (though you can try).

I think the solution is to write your own downloader middleware, which will download files from FTP servers using (haven't tried):

```
urllib2.urlopen("ftp://user:password@host.example.com/rest/of/the/url")
```